"Requires newer sdk version #32" but it is 32 SDK
I'm getting error trying to install apk build on my device

sn1.11.2picoChinaDev.apk: /data/local/tmp/_stream.apk could not be
installed [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Failed parse during
installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1421327728.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML
file line #8): Requires newer sdk version #32 (current version is
#29)]

But I am setting everything right, in Unity I set min. sdk version to 32. Also I checked builded apk using apktool and result is:
version: 2.9.3
apkFileName: 1.11.2PicoChinaDev.apk
isFrameworkApk: false
usesFramework:
  ids:
  - 1
  tag: null
sdkInfo:
  minSdkVersion: 32
  targetSdkVersion: 32
packageInfo:
  forcedPackageId: 127
  renameManifestPackage: null
versionInfo:
  versionCode: 75
  versionName: 1.11.2_7c296d
resourcesAreCompressed: false
sharedLibrary: false
sparseResources: false

Any ideas what could be wrong?

your min SDK is 32 and your device sdk is 29, change your min sdk version

You should better check the Gradle config files for the used SDK version instead of decompiling the generated APK.

Consider those steps

Double-check android:minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml.
Clean and rebuild the project.(Might be a build cache issue)
Verify  Build Settings for minimum API level.
Ensure your version fully supports API level 32, else Consider updating to the latest version.
You could also inspect any custom build scripts affecting APK generation.


Thanks tyczj it was that. Headset software support api level 29 not 32.
